# How to add different values stored in an ArrayList<String> as 'Strings'?

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, numberformatexception

I'm retrieving some numbers stored in `FirebaseDatabase` as `Strings` and storing them all in an `ArrayList <String> aList` in my app like this:

```
    mDatabase.child("child").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    aList.add(childSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                }

                Log.d("aList", String.valueOf(aList));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Here's what `log` is showing:

```
D/aList: [5.0, 3.5, 2.0, 2.5, 4.0, 3.5]
```

I tried adding these numbers like this:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble(aList.toString()) + Double.parseDouble(aList.toString());
```

but got the error: `java.lang.numberformatexception: invalid double: [5.0]`

**What I want to know** is how can I add these numbers given in the `aList` above?

Comment: try this :

`for(int i = 0 ; i < aList.size() ; i++)`

    `Double d = Double.parseDouble(aList.get(i));`

Comment: Not certain I follow. You need to loop through the array - you seem to be trying to add the whole array to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mDatabase.child("child").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                double val =0;

                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    val =val+ Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(childSnapshot.getValue()));

                }
                Log.d("!_@@_AND::>", String.valueOf(val));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

use a for loop and loop through the list to add the numbers inside the list:

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < obj.size() ; i++){
  d += Double.parseDouble(obj.get(i));
  }
  System.out.println("Current array list is:"+d);
```

**DEMO**
http://ideone.com/SxQjbR